# RISC-V ecall syscall calling convention on pk/Linux

Tags: system-calls, calling-convention, riscv

What is the calling convention for a syscall in a program that runs under the RISC-V pseudo-kernel (pk) or Linux?

Looking at the code generated by the riscv-gnu-toolchain the rules seem to be:

- syscall number is passed in `a7`
- syscall arguments are passed in `a0` to `a5`
- unused arguments are set to `0`
- return value is returned in `a0`

Is this it?

Is it really necessary to zero-out the unused arguments?

What about register `a6`? Can this be used for yet another sycall argument?

Example that calls the `exit()` syscall:

```
li    a0, 1               # argument that is used by the syscall
li    a1, 0               # unused arguments
li    a2, 0
li    a3, 0
li    a4, 0
li    a5, 0
li    a7, 93              # exit syscall number
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is basically it.

No, it isn't necessary to zero out the unused arguments. The zeroing out of unused arguments when using the riscv-gnu-toolchain (with the newlib C library) is just an artifact of the newlib sycall calling code. To keep it simple, the code has a single [`scall` (old name for `ecall`) wrapper](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-newlib/blob/7a526cdc28a3c4acce98e8a99b06562452c90d07/libgloss/riscv/internal_syscall.h#L24-L55) with 6 syscall arguments. Thus, the `exit()` implementation just [calls that wrapper with some additional zeroes](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-newlib/blob/7a526cdc28a3c4acce98e8a99b06562452c90d07/libgloss/riscv/sys_exit.c).

As of 2020, the [maximum number of syscall arguments in Linux is 6](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4.13/source/include/linux/syscalls.h#L221). The same goes for the pseudo-kernel. Thus, `a6` is always unused.

Both Linux and pk supply the syscall number in `a7`. And the syscall numbers used by pk follow the Linux standard.

The [syscall(2)](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/docs/man-pages/man-pages.git/tree/man2/syscall.2?h=man-pages-5.04#n332) Linux man-page also summarizes the calling conventions on different architectures, including RISC-V. It [specifies `a1`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/docs/man-pages/man-pages.git/tree/man2/syscall.2?h=man-pages-5.04#n200) as possibly used to return a second return value, but this doesn't match the code in glibc and newlib.

Comment: I posted [a patch to the newlib mailinglist](https://www.sourceware.org/ml/newlib/2020/msg00079.html) that changes the newlib syscall calling code such that unused arguments aren't zeroed out, anymore. It's now [part of the newlib master branch](https://www.sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=newlib-cygwin.git;a=commit;h=9b51beeb2af79d2d492e59c853ebabd4560c225a).